elasticsearch updateByQuery is not working for large data
i have written a script that will create a key "source" on 4 indices of elasticsearch based on some condition . All of my 4 indices contain at least 2~3 million data . when i ran the script it added the key for only 3 entities , then i ran it again for the last entity (deals) exclusively.
At last i noticed that some significant amount of docs were not having the new key which i introduced while running script . I can confirm that the conditions written in the script were correct . Here is the script code given below

const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env')
});
const client = require('../server/utils/es-utils').initializeESConnection();

(async function addField(){

    const sq = {
        script: {
            source: `
                if (ctx._source.sourceCreated != null) {
                    if (ctx._source.sourceCreated.recordSource != null) {
                        ctx._source.sourceCreated.source = ctx._source.sourceCreated.recordSource;
                    } else if (ctx._source.sourceCreated.clientType != null) {
                        ctx._source.sourceCreated.source = ctx._source.sourceCreated.clientType.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
            `,
            lang: "painless"
        }
    };

        const indices = ['contacts','accounts','deals','crm-activities'];
        for (const index of indices) {
            const response = await client.updateByQuery({
                index: index,
                body: sq,
                wait_for_completion: false,
                refresh: true
            });
            console.log(`Updating documents in index ${index}`);
        }
})()


I need to make sure that after running the script , i shall be able to see the key "source" on all of my docs of the given 4 indices

are you checking immediately after running this script ? You need to wait for sometime as you have set wait_for_completion as false hence this script will return response immediately but task will run in background. You can use _task API to check if task are completed and then after you can do the validation.

refresh here is set to true , so iam assuming the data to be reflected as soon as operation is performed  . Also its been a day since i ran this script .
Shall i re-run it again? ofc the data will be populated eventually but still iam flabbergasted to see elasticsearch failing to write data . I was also monitoring using task API that time and was showing no error whatsoever
